# Is it possible to use [HttpHead, HttpGet] together on an action?

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, http-headers

I am trying to add support for head requests on an action by using `[HttpGet, HttpHead]`, however a 404 is returned when doing a GET/Head request with both of these attributes applied to the action. Applying one or the other works as expected, but I want both.

My action looks like:

```
[HttpHead, HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(string one, string two, string three)
{    
}
```

The project is using `.NET 4.5.1` and I don't want to modify one action to use `AcceptVerbs` for consistency purposes, is it possible to use both `GET/HEAD` attributes together on an action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `AcceptVerbs` attribute only to achieve this, I don't think there is any other way of doing this.

Also, there should be no issues using `AcceptVerbs` for consistency purpose.

Comment: @Diazole Had this helped you?

Comment: The consistency issue is that I don't particularly want one action to be decorated differently to 300~ others, but as you say, I am not sure I have a choice. I know decorating actions in this way is shorthand for `AcceptVerbs` however, this seems like it should be possible.